# What is the use for Auto FK index in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When creating a foreign key constraint in PostgreSQL **from pgAdmin** (1.12.2 in my case), the following option is checked:

```
Auto FK index
```

I would like to know if it's right to leave it checked all the time, and also understand how that overhead actually works.

For instance, the following constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE "user"
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_region FOREIGN KEY (intregionid)
      REFERENCES region (intid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Creates the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX fki_user_region
  ON "user"
  USING btree
  (intregionid);
```

Note that it creates an index **only** when creating the constraint **from pgAdmin**.

There is not much documentation about pgAdmin, and nothing specifically about that option.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? When you enable that option pgAdmin (**not** Postgres) will simply create an index on that column (as you have found out yourself). So what's unclear about that?

Comment: I would like to know how it actually works, and what's the value added of implicitly adding an index? When is it actually recommended to create an index on a foreign key constraint?

Comment: What do you mean with "*how it actually works*"? - pgAdmin simply generates the SQL to create the index. No magic about that. Regarding the necessity of the index, [consider this quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK): "*... it is often a good idea to index the referencing columns too. Because this is not always needed, and there are many choices available on how to index, declaration of a foreign key constraint does not automatically create an index on the referencing columns*"

Comment: I assume Charles Morin wonders why it is *disabled* during FK CREATE process.... well, it seems that PgAdmin4 (5.4) automatically set it to *enabled*  _after_ it created the index. So just leave it and recheck afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an Index for the Foreign Key column. By Default, the SGBD´s not created an index for FKs Columns (Index are created by default to Primary Keys and Unique Constraints).

This is a good practice to tuning your database.

Att,

Answer (score 0):

set to **No** during creation process...

[image]

and then seems to be **enabled by default**:

[image]

so everything seems to be fine!

Answer (score 0):

When you select the "Auto FK index" option, pgAdmin will generate necessary SQL code that creates an index on the specified column. It is often beneficial to index columns that are referenced. But since it isn't always necessary and there are other indexing options available, creating a Foreign Key constraint won't automatically generate an index on the referencing columns.